# git alias partially stopped working in certain repositories, exception 80000001

Tags: git, cygwin, alias

This morning I've noted that a few git alias stopped working. I've used these extensivly every day
since ~2 years back, most notably (from ~/.gitconfig):

```
[alias]
    start = checkout -b
    m = checkout origin/master
    s = status
    st = diff --staged
    co = checkout
    cm = commit
    cp = cherry-pick
    amen = commit --amend --no-edit
    word = commit --amend
    last = whatchanged -1
```

For instance

- `git s` does nothing (that I can see) while `git status` works as normal.
- `git co` will produce a `.git/index.lock` and then nothing else. Tab completion works as usual.

Interestingly this only affected a few git repositories (2 out of 5 that I've tested). I've tried
cloning an affected repository and got the same result.

I run windows cygwin 64 bit, git 2.8.3. A collegue the same git had exactly the same issue, another had no
problem (mac git 2.7.4).

I tried out `strace git co master` and found something that might be interesting:

```
12  164720 [main] git-checkout 10092 open: 3 = open(.../.git/index.lock, 0x8A02)
15  164735 [main] git-checkout 10092 getpid: 10092 = getpid()
50  164785 [main] git-checkout 10092 sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x0, 0x6000D1F90)
--- Process 10980 thread 1156 created
--- Process 10980, exception 80000001 at 00007FFC66167BF4
--- Process 10980 thread 1156 exited with status 0x80000001
--- Process 10980 thread 10968 exited with status 0x80000001
--- Process 10980 thread 5184 exited with status 0x80000001
--- Process 10980 thread 11176 exited with status 0x80000001
--- Process 10980 exited with status 0x80000001
```

I also see `exception 80000001` in `strace git s` output so I'm guessing there is a connection.

Compared to `strace git checkout master`

```
12  201575 [main] git 2480 open: 3 = open(.../.git/index.lock, 0x8A02)
15  201590 [main] git 2480 getpid: 2480 = getpid()
53  201643 [main] git 2480 sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x0, 0x6000E4790)
--- Process 2480 thread 10544 created
608  202251 [main] git 2480 sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x0, 0x6000E4890)
78  202329 [unknown (0x2930)] git 2480 pthread::thread_init_wrapper: tid 0xFFDFCE00
```

**I've also tried**

- Rebooting
- Reinstalling git
- Downgrading git
- Installing 32 bit cygwin
- Cloning the affected repository, both locally and from server
- git gc

I've also tested `GIT_TRACE=$HOME/trace-co.log git co master` which renders:

```
$ cat ~/trace-co.log
15:29:22.828814 git.c:563               trace: exec: 'git-co' 'master'
15:29:22.833672 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-co' 'master'
15:29:22.909776 git.c:286               trace: alias expansion: co => 'checkout'
15:29:22.910082 git.c:563               trace: exec: 'git-checkout' 'master'
15:29:22.910101 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-checkout' 'master'
15:29:23.060794 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'checkout' 'master'
```

This looks exactly the same in a corrupt and working repository. For checkout I get:

```
$ cat ~/trace-checkout.log
14:51:48.605505 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'checkout' 'master'
```

No the question is, how do I fix this?

Comment: Try using repo wide config and see if things work for now. Try aliasing using the config command without passing `--global` option like so `git config alias.start 'checkout -b'`. Let me know how things turned out.

Comment: Any MS update or BLODA ?  https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: @joker, all aliases are defined in global .gitconfig, I tried `git config alias.start 'checkout -b'`, globally and locally, to be sure but no difference. @matzeri There was a company wide antivirus update the day before which do seems suspicious, though I'm not sure what I can do about it. I think I should try the 32 bit cygwin. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Turns out 32-bit cygwin gave the same result

Comment: check the AV log to see if something is reported. Which AV is by the way ?  Can you exclude the cygwin dir tree from the AV activity ? You can also try to strace zsh to see if produce more output.

Comment: No it seems to be completely emtpy (trend micro), and we had a look at the event log in windows without finding anything suspicious. I've actually started setting up my environment in git for windows. It works better then I thought it would, and of course no problem with the aliases.

Comment: Some guidance for handling `trend micro` https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2016-09/msg00182.html